# Issue with 404 Error on Page Refresh After Login Redirect

Tags: reactjs, routes, refresh

I have a web application where, after successful login, users are redirected to the dashboard page at https://abc.pro/dashboard. The initial access and redirection work fine, but when I refresh the dashboard page, it results in a 404 Not Found error.

Here are some key points:

The base URL https://abc.pro works correctly.
The local development server at http://localhost:3000 functions as expected, even after refreshing http://localhost:3000/dashboard.
I've checked for common issues such as broken links, server logs, and permissions, but haven't been able to identify the root cause. The problem seems to be specific to the production environment.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue and potential fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The information you gave is not complete, but I can probably guess the problem you encountered. I'm guessing you're using `react-router` or a similar browser-based routing library. Also, you use a static file server like nginx or similar.

The routing function of `react-dom` is completely based on the browser's `history.pushState`. When the path of the url changes, it does not send an http request to the server. (see [MDN - pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)). So before you actively refresh, the web page is actually still `/index.html`. All changes to web page elements are implemented in react.

When you use `react-router` to change path to `/dashboard`, once you actively refresh the web page, the browser will request `/dashboard` from the server. But React as a SPA (Single Page Application) only provides `/index.html`. There is no `/dashboard/index.html` on the server, hence the 404 error.

The solution is that when the web server cannot find the html file corresponding to the url, it directly returns `/index.html` instead of a 404 error.

As for why the problem does not occur in the development environment, it is because webpack has already completed this operation for you.

The following are solutions for common web servers:

`nginx`

```
server {
    # ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # ...
}
```

`express`

```js
// before app.listen() and after other code
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'index.html'));
})

app.listen(3000)
```

See also: [React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

My English is not good, so I used Google Translate for some sentences, and the sentences may not be fluent.